# Istio Version - Template_Version_And_Istio_Version_Mismatched

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar, servicemesh, istio-operator

We are facing issue w.r.t Istio running on the K8s Cluster and see the below error in the “Istio-sidecar-injector” pod. Current Istio Version used is 1.3.8

Failed to parse template: template: inject:1: function “Template_Version_And_Istio_Version_Mismatched_Check_Installation” not defined {{ Template_Version_And_Istio_Version_Mismatched_Check_Installation }}

Based on the analysis so-far, we found someone has made changes to the deployment and can see istiod added and probably due to that it is breaking which is 1.11.3 version

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, and the reason was my client version did not match control plane version and data plane version. You just need to reinstall it and make sure the versions match.